# unset string offset in php

Tags: php, string, unset

I'm trying to delete the letter p at the offset 1 of the below string.

```
$str = "apb";
unset($str[0]);
var_dump($str);
```

I'm getting a fatal error saying `Cannot unset string offsets`. Any suggestions?

Comment: unset is for removing a `variable` from a memory, but **not** _part of it_. One exception is an `array` - you can remove an element from it with unset($array['key']), but that's because an array is `a list of variables`, stored separately in RAM. A string is continuous stream of bytes in memory which is allocated/de-allocated in one go as you set/unset a string variable. In other words - string is **not** an array (albeit you can access it with an indexing operator), so you can't unset a char - just to overwrite it with another

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas hmm, would `$str[0] = ""` do the trick then?
EDIT: oh you meant char as **type** not as _character_. This is a no then, sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unset is there to **unset** the **variable**:

```
$str = "apb";
echo $str;
unset($str);
echo $str; // Undefined variable
```

**Str_replace** is a easy way to do, what you want. Replace "p" with "":

```
$newStr = str_replace("p", "", $str);
echo $newStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substrings (`substr()`):

```
$str = "apb";
$str = substr($str, 1);
var_dump($str);
```

This will strip the first char off a string

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:`$str = "apb";$newstr = $str[0].$str[2];`

OR if you're want to loop through:

```
$str = "apb";

$newstr = '';
for($i = 0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
    if($i == 1) continue;
    $newstr .= $str[$i];
}
```